# How to perform multiple boolean conditions in a whole DataFrame (row by row)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the next `DataFrame`:

```py
      open     high      low    close       volume
0  62.8571  63.9285  62.7714  63.5642   82641944.0
1  63.6642  64.9285  63.5014  64.5114   88379522.0
2  61.7014  63.6857  61.4428  63.2757  112681030.0
3  62.5928  63.6399  62.0285  62.8085  113921367.0
4  63.4357  64.0499  62.6028  63.0505  110727309.0
..      ..       ..       ..       ..           ..
```

And currently I have the next code to generate a "bool"(0,1,-1) `Series` depending con multiple conditions (selecting 2 by 2 rows. In other cases I will need 3/4 rows in each iteration/calculation):

```py
def check_pattern(data):
    engulfed_bar_range = data.iloc[-2]['close'] - data.iloc[-2]['open']
    if abs(engulfed_bar_range) >= params:
        if engulfed_bar_range > 0:
            return -1*((data.iloc[-1]['open'] > data.iloc[-2]['close']) and \
                   (data.iloc[-1]['close'] < data.iloc[-2]['open']))
        else:
            return +1*((data.iloc[-1]['open'] < data.iloc[-2]['close']) and \
                   (data.iloc[-1]['close'] > data.iloc[-2]['open']))
    return False


res = []
for index in range(1, len(all_data)):
    data = all_data.iloc[index-1:index+1]
    res.append(check_pattern(d))
s = pd.Series(res)
```

There is any better/easiest/bestPerformance way of doing that? In some other cases similar to that, in which I only need the data of one column of the DataFrame, I have used `df.rolling(..)`, but in this case that I need using data of several columns I dn't know how to do it. Maybe, there is some function of numpy that I can use? Or pd.eval? (I have tried but I havn't been able to get what I want)...

Thank so much in advance for your help.

**Graphical explanation of what I'm looking for in the df:**

I want a `pd.Series` with +1 when there is a Bullish Engulfing pattern and -1 when there is a Bearish Engulfing pattern. And 0 if there is no patter at that indexes.
[image]

Comment: explain the condition you want to apply on the dataframe with the desired output

Comment: You added example dataset, now add expected output based on your example dataset and explain what your rules are. This is not a code review site.

Comment: @tawab_shakeel  sorry guys, I thought that was better to undertand only with the condition by code. But I have now added the graphically explanation of what I want to check in the DataFrame.

Comment: @Erfan sorry, I have added extra explanation.